# Can Gnome act as thin client?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, vnc

I'm wondering if Gnome can be used like VNC. Can the window manager be run on linux box A to work with linux box B?

I'm editing some videos, and the system I'd like to use is headless. So if I could use Gnome to log into the remote system, that would be great.

VNC is nice and all, but a I think Gnome would be better if it's possible.

**To clarify:** I want Gnome on linux box A to connect to the linux system of linux box B. It would work like VNC except Gnome runs on box A, not box B.

Comment: Have you already tried `ssh -X ...` (X11 forwarding)?

Comment: Is that where you determine what X session commands in ssh are output to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said in the comments, you can use SSH with X11 forwarding. You need to run a SSH server on B. Then, SSH into B on A via `ssh -X <B>` and run the programs you want in the command line.

By using X11 forwarding, windows opened on B will use the existing window manager on A, instead of being contained in a single window on A.

Comment: This seems like the closest thing to what I want that's actually possible. I'd like to run a whole gnome session through the SSH tunnel though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what I'm looking for:

[XDMCP](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/xdmcp)

> XDMCP is a remote desktop protocol. With XDMCP, one computer A running X11 can connecting computer B running X11, and interact with computer B as if one were physically at computer B. XDMCP is integrated into X.org, the default X11 server in Ubuntu. XDMCP also needs to be implemented by the display manager.

Problem is, I don't know if Linux Mint 17 supports it.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of usage i would recommend X2GO. It's a client-server software allowing you to do exactly what you need. You just need to install X2GO-server on box B and X2GO client on box A.

https://x2go.org

I'm using this setup for all my work - connecting from a thin-client-like, very old and slow computer to a remote server. You can choose if you want to run a full remote desktop or just seamless applications.